# how to give value by using module in python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

let's suppose that there's a two python file

file1

```
from math import factorial 

def factorial(n): 
      return factorial(n)
```

file2

```
from file1 import factorial 
a = input("n : ") 
print (factorial(a))
```

**Question:**

I want to give the value of `'a'` from `file2` to `file1`, but I don't know how to do it ?

Comment: Instead of importing factorial from file1 to file2, import 'a' from file2 to file1. You can directly take input in file1. What is the reason to take input in a separate file and then import it? you can take input directly in file1.

Answer (score 1):

file1

```
 import math
 def fact(n): 
  return math.factorial(n)
```

file2

```
from file1 import fact 
a = int(input("n : "))
print (fact(a))
```

First of all import `math module` in file to calculate the `factorial` defined in `math module` and then import `fact` function from `file1` to `file2`

now  take some input by `input()` the number but you have to convert it to integer.